# How can i transpose csv data using java spark

Tags: java, csv, apache-spark

I am using java spark and i want to know if there is anyway i can transform the sample data given below

```
Incremental Cost Number | Approver Names                          
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
S703401                  |Ryan P Cassidy|Christopher J Mattingly|Frank E 
                         LaSota|Ryan P Cassidy|Anthony L Locricchio|Jason Monte
```

into something like this.

```
Incremental Cost Number| Approver Names                          
-------------------------------------------
S703401                | Ryan P Cassidy
S703401                | Christopher J Mattingly
S703401                | Frank E LaSota
S703401                | Ryan P Cassidy
S703401                | Anthony L Locricchio
S703401                | Jason Monte
```

Also the file i am importing is a comma separated csv file, just that a particular column contains multiple values are separated by pipeline symbol. And similarly if i have multiple values of Incremental Cost Number.

Comment: Hi @yyy - can you show us what you've tried

Comment: Hi @mrblewog i am stuck at logic level, i dont know how to proceed with it using java spark. Is there a way to do it using RDD or Dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do Something like below, if you have multiple columns

```
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

   val df = Seq(("S703401","Ryan P Cassidy|Christopher J Mattingly|Frank E 
   LaSota|Ryan P Cassidy|Anthony L Locricchio|Jason 
   Monte","xyz|mnp|abc")).toDF("Incremental Cost Number","Approver 
   Names","3rd Column")


  df.withColumn("Approver Names", explode(split(col("Approver Names"), "\\|")))
  .withColumn("3rd Column", explode(split(col("3rd Column"), "\\|")))
  .show()


   +-----------------------+--------------------+-----------+
   |Incremental Cost Number|      Approver Names| 3rd Column|
   +-----------------------+--------------------+-----------+
   |                S703401|Ryan P Cassidy|Ch...|xyz|mnp|abc|
   +-----------------------+--------------------+-----------+

   +-----------------------+--------------------+----------+
   |Incremental Cost Number|      Approver Names|3rd Column|
   +-----------------------+--------------------+----------+
   |                S703401|      Ryan P Cassidy|       xyz|
   |                S703401|      Ryan P Cassidy|       mnp|
   |                S703401|      Ryan P Cassidy|       abc|
   |                S703401|Christopher J Mat...|       xyz|
   |                S703401|Christopher J Mat...|       mnp|
   |                S703401|Christopher J Mat...|       abc|
   |                S703401|      Frank E LaSota|       xyz|
   |                S703401|      Frank E LaSota|       mnp|
   |                S703401|      Frank E LaSota|       abc|
   |                S703401|      Ryan P Cassidy|       xyz|
   |                S703401|      Ryan P Cassidy|       mnp|
   |                S703401|      Ryan P Cassidy|       abc|
   |                S703401|Anthony L Locricchio|       xyz|
   |                S703401|Anthony L Locricchio|       mnp|
   |                S703401|Anthony L Locricchio|       abc|
   |                S703401|         Jason Monte|       xyz|
   |                S703401|         Jason Monte|       mnp|
   |                S703401|         Jason Monte|       abc|
   +-----------------------+--------------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need split the second column by "|" and then use explode() function

```
df.select(col("id"), explode(split(col("a"), "\\|")).as("a")).show()

+-------+--------------------+
|     id|                   a| 
+-------+--------------------+
|S703401|      Ryan P Cassidy|
|S703401|Christopher J Mat...|
|S703401|             Frank E|
```

Comment: this works fine if i have two columns but if i have to add say 4 columns in similar fashion then will i still be able to use functionality of explode fn?

Comment: yes, you will get more more column copies, but it will work. Just try

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is the RDD way of doing things. It might be easier in Scala and Dataframe.

1. Use [SparkContext](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html) to read the file
2. More specifically you need to use [textFile()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#textFile-java.lang.String-int-) API which will give you RDD.
3. Once you have the [RDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html), you can tokenize each record based on the Comma ( this is done invoking map() API on RDD and passing the map function to it. In your case this function can be implemented as splitting comma delimited string into multiple tokens. You can use Tuple datastructure to emit the output.
4. You can choose the Tuple1 to Tuple22 based on number of fields you have. Refer [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Tuple1.html?search=tuple).
5. Step 3 should again give you back a RDD of Tuples. You run [flatMap](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#flatMap-scala.Function1-scala.reflect.ClassTag-) function on this RDD which will use the first field in the Tuple and concat it to the other required Tuple fields.
6. Once done, you can again put everything together back by concatenating all tuple fields with comma delimiter. ( This will be another map function)
7. In the end you call [saveAsTextFile()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#saveAsTextFile-java.lang.String-) to save the updated data.

Comment: can you explain step3 throughly

Comment: create a function that takes comma delimited string as an input and outputs Tuple containing the tokens. Pass that function to the rdd.map